# Processing JSON string as HTML in Angular

Tags: html, json, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have to work with a series of JSON files that have HTML inside them. I need to use that HTMl to format the body text of a series of pages and cannot use templates for this information.

I know jQuery has the .html() method which can be used to parse the JSON string as HTML.

Is there a better way using Angular? I would rather not use jQuery for my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use [ng-html-bind](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive in your html...

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

where `myHTML` is your html string...

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.myHTML = 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
```